# Tkinter Key bindings not working

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am currently working on a smal Projekt for my glider.
The Tkinter app should autostart with RPi and either open an app called XCSOAR or just simply quit.
It is working with the buttons, but since I wont have a mouse with me in the plane I need to bind it to keys.
It's already working on windows, but not on my raspberry pi.
I guess its a problem with the focus?

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        master.configure(background="white")
        master.overrideredirect(True)
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0" .format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
        master.bind("<Up>", self.xcsoar1)
        master.bind("<Down>", self.startx1)
        frame.pack()

        photo1=PhotoImage(file="XCS.gif")
        self.button1 = Button(frame, image=photo1, command = self.xcsoar, background="white")
        self.button1.image = photo1
        self.button1.pack()

        photo3=PhotoImage(file="center.gif")
        self.center = Label(frame, image = photo3, background="white")
        self.center.image = photo3
        self.center.pack()

        photo2=PhotoImage(file="RPi.gif")
        self.button2 = Button(frame, image=photo2, command = self.startx, background="white")
        self.button2.image=photo2
        self.button2.pack()

    def xcsoar(self):
        os.system('xcsoar.exe')
        root.destroy()
    def startx(self):
        root.destroy()

    def xcsoar1(self, event):
        os.system('xcsoar.exe')
        root.destroy()
    def startx1(self, event):
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
b = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

any ideas?

Comment: I'd tag rasberry pie, since the problem works on your local computer but not on that platform. Maybe an expert there has come across this problem

Comment: Also people might be turned off by your formatting; can you clean up that code dump? For example, who cares what the button image photo is, delete those lines. If the buttons work, delete those too.  Does the window geometry matter? Can you re-produce this with a single-line callback so it's easier to read? "Minimal working example" could be very useful here

Comment: Note that Up is the only key that will actually do anything.  Does it work? And the button can call xcsoar1 as well if you give event a default "event=None" as buttons don't send an event but keypresses do.

Comment: Well Up is not working to

Comment: Well Up is not working to.
DOWN should close the app.
Thank you for the other tipp already changed that.

I found out that if i write random stuff on the keyboard whille my app is runing and then closd it, i actuaääy write in the python IDLE.
Could that be the problem?
Already tried to solve that with .focus() though and it didnt work out

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but i don't know if this works for you, but try add force focus before the keybind

```py
def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        master.configure(background="white")
        master.overrideredirect(True)
        master.focus_force() ######
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0" .format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
        master.bind("<Up>", self.xcsoar1)
        master.bind("<Down>", self.startx1)
        frame.pack()
```

i add ##### just to mark where it is

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The advice is good not only for posting, but for development and debugging.  What follows is stripped down version of your code with the essential key bindings.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def up(event): print('up')
def dn(event): print('dn')

root.bind('<Up>', up)
root.bind('<Key-Down>', dn)
root.mainloop()
```

This works when run from an IDLE editor on 3.5.1, Win10.  Pressing either Up or Down keys result in a print to the IDLE shell. How about on your computer?  How about on your RPi?

Comment: Thank you, i will take care of the MCVEs next time. =)

This code works for me on the RPi and on Windows.
But i still dont get why it is not working in my pogramm. :/
Any ideas?

Comment: No.  Add back a bit at a time until it quits working on RPi.  If you think of it, add a comment here when you find out, as I am puzzled and curious.

Comment: So i the Problem is at at the Problem is the master.overrideredirect(true) Funktion. If i delite it everything works. Not fulscreen anymore though. Any ideas why?

Comment: The docstring for `.overrideredirect` just says "Instruct the window manager to ignore this widget".  Not helpful. The tk doc at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M56 says much the same more verbosely.    http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html says to call `update_idletasks` first.  But I dont't seem to need to.  Both references indicate that behavior is system specific.

Comment: `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)` is a better way to go fullscreen, if it works on a particular system.  `root.attributes()` will list the attributes available on the particular system.  I have no idea if `-fullscreen` is universal now.  The obsolete `help(root.attributes)` does not list it, but it has been recommended for years, and  http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M8 suggests that it should not raise on any system.